LLVM IR: ".s" file vs ".ll" file vs ".bc" file
I read that the '.ll' file is equivalent to the '.bc' file except that '.ll' is more human readable. But is '.ll' machine independent? I see references to x86_64 in my '.ll' file. In my '.s' file I don't see any of those references (just a reference to the version of my clang compiler), but I thought that's the assembly code, which should be machine dependent. I just want a human readable and machine independent representation that I can run with an interpreter/jit compiler.
By the way, I generate these intermediate files as follows:
clang -S -save-temps *.c
The ll file can be obtained from the bc file using:
llvm-dis-14 file.bc

Note: machine dependent is not a well defined term, and you are using (if I interpret correctly) in a non-standard way. Is webassembly machine independent? (but it is assembly code). (Java/Python) virtual machine uses opcodes (so sort of assembly): Java, Python ,etc. which are machine independent but I would say less portable then C source code. Note: There are various C intepreters (yes, interpreters, not compilers), and many transcoder which can transform to Java/Python and other code. -- To me it is not clear the link between your aim, and the file formats

Yes I think webassembly is a good choice for what I want to do. I am trying now to obtain the .ll file with wasm32/wasm64 as the target with clang. I have some issues where it is not finding basic includes, but I am working on that. Thanks.

The following works for me: apt install wasi-libc; clang --sysroot=/usr --target=wasm32-wasi -S -emit-llvm *.c

It really depends on how your LLVM IR was obtained. Certainly LLVM IR obtained from platform / target-dependent languages such as C or C++ is machine dependent: think about compile-time constants such as sizeof(long) or sizeof(void*), macro expressions and other things frontend should use to adhere to C/C++ ABI, etc. This does not include more lower-level things such as inline assembly.
Certainly, there are ways to produce target-independent LLVM IR. But it is the job of frontend to ensure this.

But if I compile to the target wasm32/wasm64 then the resulting LL file is platform independent right? (Even though it came from a C source code file)
